# Mustache.js extrange behavior with "link" Keyword

Tags: javascript, mustache

I just noticed that when I use something like:

```
var template = '{{#link}} {{&link}} {{/link}}';
var json = {
  link: "http://google.com"
};
var html = Mustache.render(template, json);
```

The output is

```
<a href="undefined">http://google.com</a>
```

But as far as I know there aren't any built-in functionality for links, right?
Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a WTFJS!

You're calling `String.prototype.link`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link

… and it's not doing what you think it should, because that function doesn't do what anyone thinks it should. There are a lot of fixes, but do yourself a favor and just don't name that property `link`.